# Error when importing flat file into Azure SQL from SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, ssms

I am trying to import a CSV into our Azure SQL database.  I'm using SSMS, and started the import by Right Clicking on the database, selecting Tasks and Import Data.  There are 51k records, and the whole file is about 56M.  It imported 36k records and then errored out.

When I do these it's usually some weird character that causes the issue, so I skip the record and move on.  I removed all completed plus 10 to be safe.  The resulting file is 14M and 15k records.  When I tried to import the remaining records I received the following errors:

```
Messages
Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The service has encountered an error processing your request. Please try again. Error code 4896.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
 
Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Destination - raw_order_master2.Inputs[Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "Destination - raw_order_master2.Inputs[Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
 
Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Destination - raw_order_master2" (806) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Destination Input" (819). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

Quick google showed that a common issue is lack of memory.
I have Windows 11, 124GB free on my SSD drive, and 64GB of ram that according to TaskMgr is 67% free.

So I don't think that is the issue, but the errors are so vague that I have no idea what it might be.  I'm hoping someone might have some other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try just query that *.csv file from the file system without loading it into a database via `OPENROWSET...`, and profile the data.

Here is a conceptual example for a file with the pipe as a separator.

Useful tips:

- While profiling, you can control line ranges via two parameters:
  **FIRSTROW** and **LASTROW**.
- You can start with all columns as `xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"` in the
  format file, modifying later to match the real data types in the
  destination table.
- Use *'input.err'* file to see and analyze logged errors.

[XML Format Files (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/xml-format-files-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

**SQL**

```
SELECT *
FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK 'e:\Temp\input.csv'
   , FORMATFILE = 'e:\Temp\input_format.xml'  
   , ERRORFILE = 'e:\Temp\input.err'
   , FIRSTROW = 2 -- real data starts on the 2nd row
   , LASTROW = 3 -- real data up to that row
   , MAXERRORS = 100
   ) AS tbl;
```

**input.csv**

```
"ID"|"Name"|"Color"|"LogDate"|"Unknown"
41|Orange|Orange|2018-09-09 16:41:02.000|
42|Cherry, Banana|Red,Yellow||
43|Apple|Yellow|2017-09-09 16:41:02.000|
```

**input_format.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <RECORD>
      <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='|' MAX_LENGTH="70"/>
      <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='|' MAX_LENGTH="70" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='|' MAX_LENGTH="70" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='|' MAX_LENGTH="70" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='\r\n' MAX_LENGTH="70" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
   </RECORD>
   <ROW>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="ID" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Name" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="Color" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="LogDate" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="Unknown" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
   </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```